# Uncaught Error: INDEX_SIZE_ERR on iPad ONLY

Tags: html, ipad, canvas, drawimage

I'm doing some canvas drawing in an application and it all works great in every browser (except the obvious ie7/8) but I've also gotta make it work on the iPad.  When I look at my debug console on the iPad I see this error:

INDEX_SIZE_ERR:DOM Exception 1: Index or size was negative, or greater than the allowed value

I looked at some of the other threads on here about the error but none of them seem to apply as answered (especially so because I don't see this error on the desktop version either).

The error happens in this portion of code:

```
base.draw = function(x, y) {
        // ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas[0].width, canvas[0].height);
        console.log("base.draw()");
        console.log(x);
        console.log(y);
        console.log(canvasWidth);
        console.log(canvasHeight);
        console.log($(largeImage).width());
        console.log($(largeImage).height());
        ctx.drawImage(largeImage, x, y, canvasWidth, canvasHeight, 0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
    }
```

For the logs I'm getting all positive numbers and width/height are correct.  largeImage refers to an image that is part of the HTML markup so I don't think it's an issue with the image not being loaded before trying to draw it (and as stated, the width/height log properly so I'm assuming this is not the issue).

Anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening on the iPad but not on the desktop?